# How to display list of values in Iphone programming except using UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my app I have four fields and each of them is list of values.

Now if I use a `UIPickerView` with 4 components, and then the whole `View` becomes too congested and ugly for the user's liking.

Is there any better and cleaner way to display these list of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a customized uitableview to achieve this...

By having 4 labels which displays the respective values. Also you can change the height of the cell to make it look better.

Hope this helps you...

Comment: i m having 100 values in each component and there are 4 such components then using tableview will be helpful? If yes do please provide some more information as i am a newbie.

Comment: You will have to create a NSMutableArray containing NSDictionary with 4 objects and keys. then you can use the count of the array to get the no of rows in the tableview and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath you can display the value from the array according to your requirements.

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting a clear idea of what kind of implementation you are suggesting. Please give a rough pictorial view. Even a rough screenshot will help. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks Neways Mr Atulkumar V. Jain. :]

Answer (score 2):

For small number of choices I recommend using segmented controls.
But in your case, a navigation controller (with its associated tableview for components and possible values) seems to be the best way forward. Have a look at the Settings app on your device.

Comment: I think this is best way ... UITableView